# AirFlow is triggering DAG with previous valid Run date

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG running every Monday with the following specification:

```
dag = DAG(
    'my_name',
    description='my_desc',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 11 * * 1',
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False)
```

It was running for a few weeks before I turn if off:

- 5/13 (it was turned on)
- 5/20 (it was turned on)
- 5/27 (it was turned OFF)
- 6/03 (it was turned OFF)

Today I am turning on the DAG expecting it to run only on 6/10 (next Monday) and it's running at the same moment with run date set to 5/27 even with catchup=False. Does anyone have any idea why? What should I do if I want the DAG to start running only next Monday, on 6/10?

Thanks!